# "May I know what the status of my application is" or "May I know what is the status of my application?"

Tags: word-order, inversion

Which should be the correct sentence? I think the latter is the correct one, while my friend picks the former.

Comment: For the latter do you mean "May I know what is the status of my application?"

Comment: The whole “May I know” thing may be a bit overly formal, but if I were to use it, I’d say, “May I know the status of my application?” you don’t need the “what is” construction at all.

Comment: Can you explain why you think doubling the "is" could possibly be correct?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, the former should not have "is"

Comment: @Jim I agree. I am just wondering what should be the correct sentence for this type of overly formal question. Another similar problem: "May I know what your name is" or "May I know what is your name"

Comment: Again, “May I know your name?”

Comment: @Jim Yes, in the end I use "May I know the status of the application", which is more concise. What is the second best choice, if you would to choose?

Comment: It is: “*May I know what the status of my application is?*”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I know what the status of my application is? (correct)

Affirmative: John is here.

Interrogative: Is John here?

An affirmative statement has affirmative syntax. The above example is not a question.

Note: A question has one question form, not two. For example:

What is the difference?

Can you tell me what the difference is?

(Can you tell me? is interrogative syntax, followed by affirmative syntax.)

Can you tell me what the difference is between apples and oranges?